# How to enforce a unique field with respect to other fields?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I wanted to make sure there were no duplicate timestamps in my table but then I found that it may be problematic if I simply use `UNIQUE`, because right now my table has:

```
_ID field (autoincrement)
Account ID (integer, links to an account table)
Category ID (integer, links to a category table)
Value (the value of this category for this account)
Timestamp (the timestamp of this value of this category for this account)
```

Is there a way to designate the timestamp field as unique within the context of the account ID and category ID? As in, it should not be possible to put in two values for a single timestamp, with respect to account and category. But the timestamp may show up multiple times in the table as a whole, either because it corresponds to other Categories and/or Accounts.

Comment: Do you really need that? Maybe what you are after can be handled differently.

Comment: I need it because I don't want people inserting duplicates

Comment: You can use multiple columns `UNIQUE(account, category,timestamp)`,

Comment: @dnoeth How would I incorporate that into a make-table statement?

Comment: I don't know exactly about `sqlite`, but usually it's `CREATE TABLE ...(column definition, UNIQUE(account, category,timestamp))`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger and check whatever constraint you need:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    database.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER UNIQUE_TIMESTAMP_TRIGGER " +
            "AFTER INSERT ON MY_TABLE FOR EACH ROW " +
            "BEGIN " +
            " SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Timestamp not unique') WHERE " +
            "  EXISTS(SELECT TIMESTAMP MY_TABLE T2 " +
            "   WHERE T2.TIMESTAMP = NEW.TIMESTAMP AND T2.ACCOUNT_ID = NEW.ACCOUNT_ID) " +
            "END; ");
}
```